# Initialization list c++ with complex parameter

Tags: c++

I've got a class:

```
class Foo {
private:
  Other bar;
};
```

and Other class:

```
class Other {
public:
Other(std::list<int> l, ...other parameters...);
};
```

`Other` doesn't have a default contructor and I can't add it. How can I initialize the attribute bar? I mean I need to create a list, I need to add some item and so on, so it's really difficult to use the initialization list because I need to write code to fill the list. How can I do? I think I can use a pointer instead, but I'd like to avoid dynamic allocation.

Comment: _"... so it's really difficult to use the initialization list."_ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to create the object, and use that in the initialiser list:

```
static Other make_bar() {
    std::list<int> l;
    // fill the list, do whatever else you need
    return Other(l, ...);
}

Foo() : bar(make_bar()) {}
```

Or you could use something like [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) to defer initialisation without requiring dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a constructor in `Foo` using:

```
Foo() : bar(std::list<int>()) {}
```

Comment: I can't do it, I need to fill the list before.

Comment: @greywolf82, then it's clear that you need the solution provided by MikeSeymour.